# Сделать текст в блоке на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять текст в блоке **block__text** на одном уровне? Желательно решение на flexbox

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 363px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.block .block__title {
  padding: 26px 0 0 30px;
  width: 230px;
  font-family: league_gothicregular, serif;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: #076e9f;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block .block__title .block__subtitle {
  color: #878787;
  font-family: "Arial MT", serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.block .block__title .block__subtitle .primary-color {
  color: #076e9f;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.block .block__title .block__subtitle .primary-color:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #90d4f5;
}

.block .block__text {
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 30px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  font-family: "Arial MT", serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.block .block__text .block__more {
  color: #076e9f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.block .block__text .block__more:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #90d4f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__title">
      TITLE FOR THIS BLOCK
      <div class="block__subtitle">
        Posted by <a class="primary-color">Name</a> on <a class="primary-color">Date</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block__text">
      <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, <br> nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. <br> Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.
      </p>
      <a class="block__more">more...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__title">
      TITLE FOR THIS BLOCK ON TWO ROW
      <div class="block__subtitle">
        Posted by <a class="primary-color">Name</a> on <a class="primary-color">Date</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block__text">
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, <br> nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. <br> Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. <br> Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.eget
        lacinia...
      </p>
      <a class="block__more">more...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: убрать `space-between`?

Comment: @meine высота блоков должна быть одинакова.

Comment: Высота всего блока? или высота блока с текстом должны быть одинаковые?

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял о чем вы

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/Jjjommw)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.grid__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 840px;
  margin: -20px;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block {
  height: 100%;
}

.block__inner {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block__text {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.block__more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__inner">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__inner">
          <div class="block__title">Hello there</div>

          <div class="block__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, rerum?</div>

          <div class="block__more">more</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__inner">
          <div class="block__title">Hello there</div>

          <div class="block__text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam provident blanditiis quidem soluta nisi dignissimos tempore illum aperiam quis mollitia.</div>

          <div class="block__more">more</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: высота блоков одинакова. В одном блоке заголовок в одну строку, в другом в две. подзаголовок 1 строка. и текст блока как в примере

Comment: @Besstrashnii, что? извините, что не включил свои телепатические способности сегодня